# MySQL query optimization with between or larger than > condition

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization, between

Problem: slow query.

- `table1` has about 5 000 rows
- `table2` has about 50 000 rows
- timestamp format is `int(11)`
- MySQL - 20 seconds (with indexes)
- PostgreSQL - 0,04 seconds (with indexes)

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN table2 
      ON table2_timestamp BETWEEN table1_timestamp - 500 
                              AND table1_timestamp + 500 ;
  ```

Can anybody help me with optimize this query for MySQL?

Explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  a   index       a   9       2   Using index
1   SIMPLE  b   index   b   b   9       5   Using index
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `table1_timestamp`  bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `a` (`table1_timestamp`) USING BTREE 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `table2_timestamp`  bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `a` (`table2_timestamp`) USING BTREE 
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points spring to mind but both feel like long-shots.  Realistically it looks as though there shouldn't be much you can do to your query assuming your example is an accurate representation.

1 : You are using BIGINT which has a maximum value of 9x10^18 (SIGNED).  INT has a max value of 4x10^9 (UNSIGNED), compared to days timestamp which is around 1.4x10^9 (all values approximate) and so consider changing the data type of that column in both tables from `BIGINT` to `INT UNSIGNED` or `DATETIME`

2 : The ROW_FORMAT is COMPACT which may cause issues with BTREE indexes ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-row-format-antelope.html)).  You are dealing with INT data types and so a ROW_FORMAT of FIXED would suffice so try changing to `ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` on both tables

3 : If always expecting rows to be returned from table2 for table1 rows then INNER JOIN would be more efficient than LEFT JOIN

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately, it did not help - with "limit 100" it runs about 13 seconds.

Comment: Well the limit wouldn't really help with the JOIN.  Are you expecting there to ALWAYS be rows in table2 for every row in table1?  If so, have you tried an INNER JOIN?

Comment: I tried LIMIT on table1 so i think that it works... but it looks that INNER JOIN gets it done! Thanks a lot!